# Can't access %node context keywords in Panels & Panelizer

Tags: panels, chaos-tool-suite

Context keyword sunstitutions for the node being displayed are showing up blank!

Latest drupal installation with Dev versions of Panels, Panelizer, ctools, etc...

I have a node type that has 2 entityreferences to 2 other node types.  One of the fields in the main nodetype is "field-location-detail", which is -not- present in any other nodes.  I set up Panelizer to handle the Full Content Display & also set up relationships to the other entities.  When I try to use the context keyword "" in a Custom Content Panel, nothing shows up.

First indication of the problem is that on the Context screen, the same keyword/field shows up multiple times:

```
Summary of contexts
Built in context    This node
  ...
  %node:field_location_detail --> Where in this location?
  %node:field-location-detail --> Where in this location?
From "This node"    Node from Node (on Node: Select a Location [field_event_location])
  ...
  %node:field_location_detail --> Where in this location?
  %node:field-location-detail --> Where in this location?
```

Then, when I captured the data going through function ctools_context_keyword_substitute($string, $keywords, $contexts, $converter_options = array()), the problem becomes clear.  The 3 objects passed in the $contexts argument have keywords of "none", "node", & "node_2".  So the local context variables are *always* overwritten.

I guess that the root problem is that the keyword being assigned isn't incremented initially, so it starts from "node" in stead of "node_1".

Anyone knows where that should happen?